# How to show 4 <li> on one row and the others 4 <li> on the other one

Tags: php, html, css

I have the query on php which takes a lot of images from database, I need to show 4 images on the first row, the other 4 images on the next row and so on.

I thought I could do that with the help css, but I can't =(

**HTML**

```
<div id="photo_block" style="border:2px dotted <?echo $color;?>; height:1000px;" >

    <?
        while ($item=$select_items->fetch()) {
    ?>

<ul class="items">
    <li>
        <div class="item_block">
            <img src="<?echo $item['src']?>">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

    <?
        }
    ?>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#photo_block{
    width:800px;
}
.items li{
    display: inline;
}
.items li .item_block img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

thank you for helping me!

Comment: It's simpler to use a table in this case (without borders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you should reset the padding and margin of the `ul` element
2. your img size is set to `100px` so they will fit inside your `#photo_block` 8 times in a row

How about: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ntzq/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new list with one item for every separate image?
I would not use a list at all, and just put them in `div`s four at a time, then scale the images to (a little under) 25%.

```
<div class='imagerow'>
<?
    $i = 0;
    while ($item=$select_items->fetch()) {
      if($i > 0 && $i % 4 == 0) {
?>
</div>
<div class='imagerow'>
<?
      } // end if
?>
 <img src="<?echo $item['src']?>">
<?
   } // end while
?>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.imagerow img { width: 24.75%; }
```

where the width is just short of 25% because experience taught me that if you take exactly 25% the last one often still overruns onto the next line.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="photo_block" style="border:2px dotted <?echo $color;?>; height:1000px;" >
<ul class="items">
   <? while ($item=$select_items->fetch()) { ?>
    <li>
      <div class="item_block">
         <img src="<?echo $item['src']?>">
       </div>
    </li>
   <? } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#photo_block{
    width:500px;
}
.items li{
    width:100px;
    margin-right:5px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.items li .item_block img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` instead of `display: inline`, then add a new rule that does a `clear: left` every 4th `<li>` element.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="photo_block" style="border:2px dotted <?echo $color;?>; height:1000px;" >

  <ul class="items">
    <? while ($item=$select_items->fetch()): ?>

    <li>
        <div class="item_block">
            <img src="<?echo $item['src']?>">
        </div>
    </li>

    <? endwhile ?>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#photo_block{
    width:800px;
}
.items li{
    float: left;
}
.items li:nth-child(4n)
{
    clear: left;
}
.items li .item_block img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```